# Size of types when writing into BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, .net, size, binarywriter

Size of each character in `ASCII` (`StreamWriter`) takes `1` byte whether its a number or character.

Similarly what will be the size of each character, integer in binary? (`BinaryWriter`). Can some one explain in brief?

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 2`, so single character is *2 bytes* long; however, the size of `Stream` depends on encoding (Ascii, UTF-8 etc.) and characters itself: `aaa` (3 English letters `a`) can be shorter than `ааа` (3 *Russian* letters `а`)

Comment: A `char` in C# is UTF-16, this means each character takes 2 bytes. An intergral type depends on the it's size, meaning it can be either a single byte (`Byte`),  a `Short` (16bit), `int` (32Bit), `long` (64bit).

Comment: Almost (but not quite) every time I see someone use `BinaryWriter`, they use it for badly considered reasons. What is it that you need to do here? Would a binary serializer be a better choice? (there are several to choose from)

Comment: Size in bytes clearly specified in each override of `Write` method - not really sure what other information you need - i.e.  [BinaryWriter.Write(Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24e33k1w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - "Writes a four-byte signed integer to the current stream and advances the stream position by four bytes."...

Comment: @  Marc Gravell , Every One Has Their Own Choice In Dealing With Their Project . Still People Say's Use Method Instead Of Properties And Few Say's That Use Properties Instead Of Method But After All It Depend's Upon Circumstances . I Am Using BinaryWriter Because Of It's Size

Comment: Why Are You Capitalizing First Character In Every Word? Becuase Of It's Size? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with difference between `StreamWriter` and `BinaryWriter`. `StreamWriter` is for writing a textual representation to a stream.  `StreamWriter` converts anything that is written (via Write* method) into a string, then converts via the encoding to bytes, and writes the bytes to the underlying stream.

`BinaryWriter` is for writing raw "primitive" data types to a stream. For numeric types it takes the in memory representation, does some work up to normalize the representation (e.g. to handle differences in endianess), and then writes the bytes to the underlying stream. Note that it also has an encoding provided in the constructor. This is used only for converting `char` and `string` into to bytes. The default encoding is UTF8.

> Size of each character in ASCII (StreamWriter) takes 1 byte whether its a number or character.

This is statement is somewhat confusing to me. Let me clarify. The `int` 1 will be converted to the string "1" which encodes in ASCII as 49 which is indeed one byte, but 100 will be converted to the string "10000" which encodes in ASCII to  49 48 48 48 48, so that's 5 bytes. If using `BinaryWriter` both would occupy 4 bytes (the size of an `int`).

> Similarly what will be the size of each character, integer in binary? (BinaryWriter). Can some one explain in brief?

The size of a `char` depends on the encoding used for both `BinaryWriter` and `StreamWriter`. The size of numeric types like `int`, `long`, `double` are the sizes of the underlying types, 4, 8, and 8 bytes respectively. The amount of data written is documented in each [Write overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7cxfc93(v=vs.110).aspx) of BinaryWriter. Strings are treated distinctly from `char[]` in BinaryWriter and will have their length prefixed before the encoded bytes are written.